# Вызов события в WebWorker

Tags: javascript, node.js, webworkers

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const Worker =  require("webworker-threads").Worker;

const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);

var worker = new Worker(function(){
    postMessage("Init");
    function delay(milliseconds) {
        let time = new Date().getTime() + milliseconds;
        while (new Date().getTime() < time) {
        }
    }
    let variable = 0;
    this.addEventListener("data",function(data){
        postMessage(data);
        variable = data.variable;
    });
    this.onmessage = function(event) {
        if (event.data.variable) 
            variable = event.data.variable;
        else{
            for (var i = 0; i < event.data; i++) {
                postMessage(i + " " + variable);
                delay(1000);
            }
        }
        self.close();
    };
});

worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
};

app.get('/a', (req, res) => {
    worker.postMessage(10);
    res.json('Success');
});

app.get('/b', (req, res) => {
    worker.dispatchEvent("data", {variable: 1});
    res.json('Success');
});

server.listen(80);
```

При открытии маршрута `/a` в консоли всё выводится правильно

```
0 0
1 0
```

и так далее. Но при открытии `/b` во время выполнения предыдущей задачи, процесс полностью останавливается и отказывается запускаться.
Вообще, требуется во время работы WebWorker передать в него какие либо данные. Есть решение?

Comment: RTFM: *".dispatchEvent( event ) **Currently unimplemented**."*

Comment: @PavelMayorov, какие тогда есть предложения для выполнения данной задачи?